# Is there JPA annotation to join only a single foreign column?

Tags: jpa

Given

```
@Entity
Class Students{
private Long profid;

@Formula (value  = (select p.name from Prof p where p.id = profid))
private getProfsName;
...
}

@Entity 
Class Profs {
private Long id;
private String name;
... (getters/setters)
}
```

Surely there must be something more direct than @Formula? I don't see any example of using @OneToOne where you can select anything other than the entire foreign entity. I just want a single property of the foreign entity.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a [Secondary](http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/SecondaryTable)[Table](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0355__JPA/SecondaryTableWithPrimaryKey.htm)